# Cannot change appearance of WooCommerce "Thanks you for your Order" page by editing child theme CSS

Tags: css, woocommerce

I wish to change the appearance of this page

https://www.wizardmodels.ltd/checkout/order-received/21061/?key=wc_order_NesCNU4ih80Xn

generated after an order made in chrome's incognito mode

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XFhM.jpg)

all CSS I write into the child theme *appearance>edit* seems not to affect this page, for example

```
.order_details ul li {
    padding: 0em 0em!important;
}
```

and variants thereof. Is there something about the Thank you.... page? Is it like an email with CSS editing through PHP snippet?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child style is loaded, The problem is because of `.order_details` is the ul and not the ul container :

[image: inspectElement]

Simply change your CSS selector from `.order_details ul li` to `ul.order_details li`.

Comment: sorry about that, I was typing and editing screenshots and didn't see your answer.

Comment: Cheerychops , I checked your child style now, and not changed yet, if you using cash plugin same as wp rocket and ... clear cash and refresh. This is your style : check last line : (Not changed) :https://www.wizardmodels.ltd/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/style.css?ver=1.0

Comment: Okay turned caching off, deleted cache, refreshed but your link shows that it is still not updating ? Using WP Super Cahce

Comment: Bingo - seems to work now, can see edited CSS and effects changes to the page. Thanks

Comment: Sorry If I have caused offence, it's just the solution was to turn off and super cache and to amend the CSS. I can give two solutions. Although I do seem to get into trouble every time I used Stack :(